# I can't fill my Roster in Madden 12 Ultimate Team?

Tags: madden-12

I started Ultimate Team with the starter pack and after I played a game my LG was injured. I cannot fill this spot because my only other lineman are all starters. Now I can't play a game and I don't have enough coins to buy a pack.